XCM Transactions - Polkadot to Asset Hub (Statemint)
I understood how to create a message to send some DOT from polkadot to asset hub.
My main question is, how to track the whole flow of the transactions to be sure it succeeded?
To contextualise, I have two ws listeners which listens to new block headers for each chain.
How can I say ok this extrinsic is what I have sent and this extrinsic is what has been created on destination chain ? Is there a way to map the two extrinsics ? Or is there a way to identify the extrinsic on the destination chain by checking involved addresses ?
Thanks

You can listen for the MessageQueue::Processed event on the destination and match the id field with the messageId field you get from the xcmPallet.Sent event on the sender.
On sender:


On destination:

Then you know your message was executed on the destination on that block and can check all other events there.

Thanks for your answer. But looking at this example (https://bifrost.subscan.io/xcm_message/polkadot-b59122779bf56b71a4cc9a4cc393fce2be98e8a3), we can see the two extrinsics have been inserted in a block at the same time, so i am scared that I could miss some events on destination chain. Is there a way to compute the message id before hand ? If you have an example in TS could be great

Is it a correct implementation ?
`const xcmMessage = api.tx.xcmPallet.reserveTransferAssets(
{ V1: { parents: 1, interior: { X1: { Parachain: destinationChain } } } },
{ V1: { interior: { X1: { AccountId32: { id: destinationAccount, network: 'Any' } } } } },
[{ ConcreteFungible: { id: { Concrete: { parents: 1, interior: 'Here' } }, amount: assets.amount } }],
0
).toHex();
// Compute the XCM hash
const xcmHash = blake2AsHex(xcmMessage);`

The message id is not the hash of the message, it takes into account on-chain entropy as well. That's why it's best to get it from events.
If you go to the page of the sender and destination, you can see the message id in xcmPallet.Sent in the sender and messageQueue.Processed in the destination being the same

Got it. I wonder if I can have some problems syncing the extrinsics. It would mean I need to store all messageIds in destination chain to be able to map it when needed right ? Imagine the source chain node is down, the destination chain extrinsic will be processed first by my handler and so when source chain node recovers it it will be handled after destination chain one. I just want to have confirmation of that.

And which event is thrown when destination chain processing fails ?

The same event is triggered but with success: false.
